# Protect PHP Session ID in Custom Handler

Tags: php, security, session

I have written a trivial custom session handler (in MySQL, but that's not relevant) which simply saves serialized session data, the session id, and the current time to a table.

While the session exists, the session id is as valuable as a password for an attacker, which leads me to believe that I should be encrypting it in some way.

Is it worthwhile to hash the session id before storing it in the database in order to force an attacker to bruteforce the session id to forge a cookie?

My site already uses HTTPS for all connections.

Comment: Is session id "encrypted" here on stackoverflow? You need to prevent malicious usage of the same session from several clients, not the identifier itself.

Comment: @zerkms, I wouldn't know unless I could read the session table.

Comment: so users on your site can read the session table?

Comment: @zerkms, Users cannot read the session table, but an attacker may some day find a flaw and be able to read the database. More secure sites than mine have had breaches.

Comment: so here in comments you're worrying about protecting your database, and in the question you're asking about encrypting session id. It looks very inconsistent.

Comment: So I would recommend you rethink the original question and ask it again, because in current revision (+ comments) it doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you're trying to prevent is that if an attacker gets access to a dump of session ids from your database, he could pose as any arbitrary user because he can use the session id as is. For this it's actually a pretty good idea to hash the id the same way you'd hash a password, so one-way lookups are possible, but the hashed value itself has become useless. Since session ids also expire quite quickly usually, there's little use in brute-forcing.

On the other hand, since session ids expire quite quickly usually, there may not be much point to it to begin with. The window of opportunity is very small for an attacker. The very fact that the attacker was able to get a dump of session ids from your database weighs much heavier and is a much worse breach, since it means the attacker probably already has access to other data as well.

It is still a worthy defense with little downsides (slight computational overhead, slightly more complicated debugging of session ids).

Comment: I agree, if your at the point where a hacker has access to your database to read the session Id your screwed anyway. Plus you could simple clear out the sessions. Your time would likely be better spent encrypting sensitive data and implementing some sort of permission escalation feature.

Comment: I have indeed set my sessions to expire quickly, but PHP uses a GC mechanism to clean them up. There's chance they could live for much longer than I expect due to probability.

Comment: @Martin Your handler could/should include an expiration check then.

Comment: @deceze, Mine does, I just wanted to leave a note for others about what I consider to be a PHP "gotcha" (session gc_maxlifetime is actually the minimum time a session will remain stored on disk)